# How to put bounds/limits on Goal Seek function in Excel without VBA?

Tags: excel, range, limits, excel-2016

I'm using **MS Office 2016 Professional Plus**.

In Excel I'm trying to minimize a value in a cell by using **What-If-Analysis** and **Goal Seek**. But there is no options to set a limits on changing cell.

Here it is:
[image]

I can only set a target cell, target value and a changing cell. But I need changing cell to be changed within certain bounds: **[0:1]** (from zero to one)

---

Is there some way I can set bounds on **Goal Seek** without involving programming with VBA so it fluctuates within specified range?

---

*Uploaded my Excel file to DropBox:* [*SOQ.xlsx*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/swvdhzu4dsjdr9l/SOQ.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi: use the solver instead of goal seek - this gives the control and flexibility you are looking for : binary constraints, integer and limits on other cell values in the linear path.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to go about it is to set your initial changing cell value to `0.5` and then go to **File> Options> Formulas** and included the following in your calculation options:

Maximum iterations: `100` 
Maxumum Change: `0.005`

Then goal seek as before

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `$B$20` to `=MAX(MIN(1,$C$20),0)`
2. Select `$C$20` for *By changing cell* in the ***Goal Seek*** window